# Name node is in safe mode. Not able to leave

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
root# bin/hadoop fs -mkdir t
mkdir: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create directory /user/root/t. Name node is in safe mode.
```

not able to create anything in hdfs

I did

```
root# bin/hadoop fs -safemode leave
```

But showing

```
safemode: Unknown command
```

what is the problem?

Solution: http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.com/2014/04/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-how-to-leave.html?m=1

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hdfs_user_guide.html#Safemode might help.

Comment: In my case, it was in safe node because resources were low (running on docker)

Comment: @BrendenBrown, here's the currently working link for Hadoop 3.2.0: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode

Comment: And here's the currently working link for the Hadoop «stable» (currently 2.9.x): http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode

Comment: the link http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-how-to-leave.html is dead, I’ll edit it out

Comment: Oh the link is dead

Comment: Could you please check if this link works? http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.com/2014/04/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-how-to-leave.html?m=1

Answer (score 229):

In order to forcefully let the namenode leave safemode, following command should be executed:

```
 bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

You are getting `Unknown command` error for your command as `-safemode` isn't a sub-command for `hadoop fs`, but it is of `hadoop dfsadmin`.

Also after the above command, I would suggest you to once run `hadoop fsck` so that any inconsistencies crept in the hdfs might be sorted out.

**Update:**

Use `hdfs` command instead of `hadoop` command for newer distributions. The `hadoop` command is being deprecated:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

`hadoop dfsadmin` has been deprecated and so is `hadoop fs` command, all hdfs related tasks are being moved to a separate command `hdfs`.

Comment: actually why this displays 'namenode is in safemode'

Comment: Basically namenode enters in safe mode in unusual situations, for example when disk is full, also in the start-up phase. Read more here; http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hdfs_user_guide.html#Safemode

Comment: I'm using Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.1.1
When I ran the `hadoop dfsadmin` command, it gave me this:
`______
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Safe mode is OFF
`______
... but still ran. Seems the suggestion by @user3316017 below is the recommended syntax.

Comment: Updated my answer as per new distributions, if anyone can help us out in establishing the exact version of apache hadoop since when these deprecations have come into picture, it would be great.

Comment: @Amar Both of these solutions "work" for me in the sense that the console prints Safe mode is OFF. However, when I try to run ./bin/hdfs dfs -put libexec/etc/hadoop input it prints Cannot create directory /user/username/input. Name node is in safe mode. What is happening?

Comment: For the case where HDFS goes to safe mode again as soon as the `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave` comand is run because cluster is full, it is sometimes possible to get out of the situation by immediately chaining a command for cleaning up stuff, e.g. `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave; hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash /path/to/stuff/to/delete`

Comment: You must be hdfs user, so `sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Answer (score 31):

try this, it will work

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Comment: this command worked for me as it can require superuser privilage..thanks @wesam

Answer (score 22):

The Command did not work for me but the following did

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

I used the `hdfs` command instead of the `hadoop` command.

Check out http://ask.gopivotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/200933026-HDFS-goes-into-readonly-mode-and-errors-out-with-Name-node-is-in-safe-mode- link too

Comment: Doc link on Hadoop Safe Mode: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode

Answer (score 12):

safe mode on means (HDFS is in READ only mode)
safe mode off means (HDFS is in Writeable and readable mode)

In `Hadoop 2.6.0`, we can check the status of name node with help of the below commands:

TO CHECK THE name node status

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode get
```

TO ENTER IN SAFE MODE:

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode enter
```

TO LEAVE SAFE mode

```
~$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Comment: TO FORCE LEAVE SAFE MODE:

~$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode forceExit

Answer (score 8):

If you use Hadoop version 2.6.1 above, while the command works, it complains that its depreciated. I actually could not use the `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave` because I was running Hadoop in a Docker container and that command magically fails when run in the container, so what I did was this. I checked doc and found `dfs.safemode.threshold.pct` in documentation that says

> Specifies the percentage of blocks that should satisfy the minimal
>   replication requirement defined by dfs.replication.min. Values less
>   than or equal to 0 mean not to wait for any particular percentage of
>   blocks before exiting safemode. Values greater than 1 will make safe
>   mode permanent.

so I changed the `hdfs-site.xml` into the following (In older Hadoop versions, apparently you need to do it in `hdfs-default.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.safemode.threshold.pct</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Try this**

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

check status of safemode

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode get
```

If it is still in safemode ,then one of the reason would be not enough space in your node, you can check your node disk usage using :

```
df -h
```

if root partition is full, delete files or add space in your root partition and retry first step.

Answer (score 5):

Namenode enters into safemode when there is shortage of memory. As a result the HDFS becomes readable only. That means one can not create any additional directory or file in the HDFS. To come out of the safemode, the following command is used:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

If you are using cloudera manager:

```
go to >>Actions>>Leave Safemode
```

But it doesn't always solve the problem. The complete solution lies in making some space in the memory. Use the following command to check your memory usage.

```
free -m
```

If you are using cloudera, you can also check if the HDFS is showing some signs of bad health. It probably must be showing some memory issue related to the namenode. Allot more memory by following the options available. I am not sure what commands to use for the same if you are not using cloudera manager but there must be a way. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Run the command below using the HDFS OS user to disable safe mode:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 0):

use below command to turn off the safe mode

$> hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave