# Hadoop: Cannot delete a directory. Name node is in safe mode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I am  trying to delete a directory in the HDFS file system, I am getting the following error:

Cannot delete *directory*. Name node is in safe mode.

How to solve this issue? Please advice.

Comment: Try below link, I think that would help you-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47415458/8856233

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you see that error that means the Namenode is in safe mode and it is almost equivalent to read-only mode.

To leave the namenode from the safemode run the below command:

$ hadoop dfsadmin –safemode leave

Comment: Although this answer was correct in 2014 it is incorrect now because this script was deprecated and does not work. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" as @Philip suggests.

Answer (score 12):

if you are using hadoop 2.9.0 or higher, use

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave` canceled safemode but as soon as I tried to delete the old directory, the system returned to safemode.

I deleted all the tmp folders that I could find related to hadoop installations but the old directory did not disappear and it could not be deleted.

Finally I used:

```
ps aux | grep -i namenode
```

and discovered that there was a running process that was using parameters from an older Hadoop implementation (different version). I killed the process using `kill pid` and finally this action removed the old directory.