# Name node is in safe mode. Not able to leave. Hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, namenode

I am new to hadoop and i am just trying to see how things work. I am following this [tutorial](https://kishorer.in/2014/10/22/running-a-wordcount-mapreduce-example-in-hadoop-2-4-1-single-node-cluster-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit/) for WordCount . But in step 9 when i execute

```
hduser@spyros:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ hadoop dfs -mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/input
```

I am taking this message :

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

mkdir: Cannot create directory /usr/local/hadoop/input. Name node is in safe mode.
```

I tried everything from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave) and i take the message:

```
Safe mode is OFF
```

but nothing changed still not able to create directory.
Is there anything else i could try?
Using Hadoop 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

Comment: check if there is any lock, also if you don't have any data on HDFS you can try format namenode and then starting the daemons.

Comment: @Vishrant i have already done format namenode... What do you mean by "check if there is any lock" because i am new to whole thing...