# Hadoop load CSV file into HDFS - error Name node is in safe mode

Tags: csv, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to load a .csv file into HDFS. For that I do this:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/cloudera/reduced.csv /user/cloudera
```

But when I submit this I'm getting:

```
copyFromLocal: Cannot create file/user/cloudera/reduced.csv._COPYING_. Name node is in safe mode.
```

I already see this post:
[Name node is in safe mode. Not able to leave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave)

But I'm still get this error...

Comment: is it a production environment or pseudo dist? what error do you get when you do `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode` leave. if it is pseudo, have you tried restating your linux host machine entirely? `sudo init 6`

Comment: When I try to put safemode as OFF i can get it but when I submit the sudo code I obtain that error