# Unable to start Hive via Terminal on Cloudera CDH5.8 VM - Bad health,Name Node is in Safe Mode

Tags: hive, hbase, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Here are the steps I have performed.
1. Started VM - Cloudera CDH 5.8 - allocated 10GB of Ram + 4 Cores.
2. Open Terminal and executed following command

```
sudo ./cloudera-manager --express --force
```

3. Open browser and logged into Cloudera Manager.
4. Started all the components.
5. All components are running in good health except HDFS,HIVE and HBASE.
6. when I looked at the cause of Bad health, I found that 'Name Node is in Safe Mode'.

I am not familiar with Admin stuff of Hadoop ecosystem, please help me troubleshoot the following issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name node is in safe mode. Not able to leave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave)

Comment: please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15803653/647053

Answer (score 0):

In order to forcefully let the namenode leave safemode, following command should be executed:

> hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave

Comment: if you are training on cloudera quickstart 
`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Comment: Why "sudo -u"? With my answer is enough