# import mysql data into hdfs contents file not read CCA

Tags: hdfs, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I want to see contents of the hdfs file which I have import mysql data using sqoop.

I ran the command `hadoop dfs -cat /user/cloudera/products/part-m-00000`.

I am getting error:

```
cat: Zero blocklocations for /user/cloudera/products/part-m-00000. Name node is in safe mode.
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave).

Answer (score 0):

It s not possible to read hdfs data when namenode is in safe mode. Leave from safe mode, run the below command,

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Then cat the file in hdfs.

Comment: Yes but it says access denied for user cloudera superuser   privilage is required   , Then I found the solution         sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave

Comment: Then I found the solution

Comment: Nice... approve the answer if it helped...:)