# How to return to the local user in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, terminal, snort

I have ubuntu 15.10 os.
I wrote a shell script to execute multiple commands which are:

Log to root " root@dalya-B5400:/home/hduser "  and enter snort directory , and open Ids mode , Convert the captured packets to text format and at last logout from this directory and root, Then log to hadoop user " root@dalya-B5400:/home/hduser " , Start all process and send the snort log file to hadoop.

I'm in account "  hduser@dalya-B5400 " which is the normal user.
I need some commands to perform  in this user: " root@dalya-B5400:/home/hduser "  so I used : $ sudo su and logged to it.
After finishing my job here, I want to return to the normal user "  hduser@dalya-B5400 "

My script  worked until log from root to hadoop user, Here I focused a problem, I used this commands (one at time) :

```
$ su - & sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@dalya-B5400
$ sudo -iu hduser
$ sudo su - hduser
```

Its logged to hadoop user but after that exit without execute the rest commands behind it.

Also I tried to call second shell script from the current , but also it give same result and don't open the normal user.

My primary shell script named snort-command and its contain this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/snort5_src
cd snort-2.9.9.0
snort -dev -n 20 -l /home/hduser/log9 -b -c /etc/snort5/snort.conf
chmod a+rwx /home/hduser/log9/snort.log.*
tcpdump -n -tttt -r /home/hduser/log9/snort.log.* > /home/hduser/log9/bigfile2.txt
sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@dalya-B5400
/home/hduser/hadoop
```

and the second shell script named hadoop and contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
hadoop fs -put /home/hduser/log9/bigfile2.txt user/hduser/li
```

Also I tried to open new terminal from the current :

```
$ gnome-terminal
```

But its also open the current user not the normal one.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by this steps:

1- Add  sudo to snort commands without login to root user so I don't need to logout later.

```
sudo snort -dev -n 20 -l /home/hduser/log9 -b -c /etc/snort5/snort.conf
sudo chmod a+rwx /home/hduser/log9/snort.log.*
sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -r /home/hduser/log9/snort.log.* > /home/hduser/log9/bigfile2.txt
```

And to run it  without a password, add this Line to visudo :

```
hduser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

2- At this point it worked until I send the file to hadoop, It give message says:

```
nameNode in safe mode
```

I found out  the problem was because Job is running before namenode is out of safemode after startup. So I started hadoop process before excuting the script few  minutes and Its worked fine .

Comment: Hint: you can also limit the permission of `hduser` instead of allowing him to use any command on your system

Comment: check this [Name node is in safe mode. Not able to leave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave) as it might be similar issue

Comment: I also did: hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave, didn't fix the problem, I fix it now by running hadoop before execute the script.

Comment: How can I  limit the permission of hduser?, I added this: hduser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL , to make it execute the script without ask for password.

Comment: can I ask you what is your specialty?

Comment: `hduser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` the last `ALL` means he can use all commands without typing the password. for example if you want to allow him to use tcpdump command only you can do `hduser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tcpdump` (to get the full path of tcpdump on your system type `whereis tcpdump`), check this [article](http://ask.xmodulo.com/use-sudo-without-password-prompt-linux.html) and also this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/how-to-restrict-to-run-commands-in-specific-directory-through-sudoers)

Comment: linux system administrator :D or so they say \o/ :'D

Answer (score 1):

You can login using a normal user through SSH and then execute commands as root (you will need to make sure that your normal user is in `sudoers`) using the following command for example:

```
sshpass -p 'mynormaluserpassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no mostafa@remotehost "whoami && id ; echo 'mynormaluserpassword' | sudo -S sh -c 'whoami; id; echo Hello from root user'"
```

The result will be as the following:

```
mostafa
uid=1033(mostafa) gid=1033(mostafa) groups=1033(mostafa)
[sudo] password for mostafa: root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
Hello from root user
```

**Explanation**:

1. I logged in using a normal user called `mostafa`
2. I executed `whomai` then `id` which printing these results:

   `mostafa
   uid=1033(mostafa) gid=1033(mostafa) groups=1033(mostafa)`
3. I executed another 3 commands `'whoami; id; echo Hello from root user'` but by using `sudo` which is the equivalent to root user and the result was as following:

   `root`

   `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

   `Hello from root user`

Also in order to use sudo I have to type a password ( unless you configured it to work passwordless ) using `echo 'mynormaluserpassword' | sudo -S` and then I used `sh -c 'whoami; id; echo Hello from root user'` to pass all the command i need to execute it as root.

So any root commands you need to execute could be added in here `echo 'mynormaluserpassword' | sudo -S sh -c 'echo Hello from root user'"`

Comment: I tried all you wrote , didn't work , I found out the main problem was because I started hadoop at the same time with job execution and this led to errors in my script.Thank you for your help :))

Comment: if you tried the same examples as provided it should work as i have tested it on a server and yes it may not work with different commands as the code itself maybe needs some modifications in this case (for example output redirection might cause an issue with my code but i have not tested it in this case ) and sorry i wasn't able to repeat the same steps as you i wanted to get a clear picture first of your situation :D, so you have solved the issue or still ?

Comment: It didn't worked because my setup is different(commands in different users), also because I added the command that start hadoop in the script while I must open hadoop before that.Yes I finally fix it :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand all of your description correctly, but I think what you're trying to say is that the remote part of the command isn't happening?  Is /home/hduser/hadoop your second script?

If yes, this should do the job:

```
cd ~/snort5_src
cd snort-2.9.9.0
snort -dev -n 20 -l /home/hduser/log9 -b -c /etc/snort5/snort.conf
chmod a+rwx /home/hduser/log9/snort.log.*
tcpdump -n -tttt -r /home/hduser/log9/snort.log.* >         
/home/hduser/log9/bigfile2.txt
sshpass -p hadoop ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@dalya-B5400 /home/hduser/hadoop
```

The problem being that you just connect to the remote machine, and it knows nothing of what's in the local script after that :)

Comment: Yes, The problem is I can't connect to the local machine again from this script, I did as you said but didn't work :l

Comment: @Dalya do you know why you cannot login to the server again?  Does this command return any errors ? `sshpass -p hadoop ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@dalya-B5400 /home/hduser/hadoop
` , Can you execute the same command manually ?

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein, because I logged to the root , after that I need to execute commands as the local user, So I need a way to log to the normal user from shell script and continue to execute commands behind it in the shell.sshpass -p hadoop ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@dalya-B5400 /home/hduser/hadoop, worked to log to the local user and execute just the first command in the second script and for the second command give this message:./hadoop.sh: line 3: hadoop: command not found
which I think it did not login to the local user in right way.