# Why is my test cluster running in safe mode?

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs, safe-mode

I'm testing some basic HDFS operations like creating directories. I have the following cluster configuration in my test:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.{HdfsConfiguration, MiniDFSCluster}

// ...

private val baseDir = new File("./target/hdfs/test").getAbsoluteFile

private val conf = new HdfsConfiguration()
conf.set(MiniDFSCluster.HDFS_MINIDFS_BASEDIR, baseDir.getAbsolutePath)
conf.setInt("dfs.safemode.threshold.pct", 0)
private val builder = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf)
private val cluster = builder.build()
cluster.waitActive()
private val fs = cluster.getFileSystem

private val host = cluster.getNameNode.getHttpAddress.getHostString
private val port = cluster.getNameNodePort
```

I find that when I run the tests, I find that I always get this error:

```
[warn] o.a.h.s.UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:erip (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create directory [...]. Name node is in safe mode.
Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
```

followed soon after by ...

```
[info]   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Cannot create directory [...]. Name node is in safe mode.
[info] Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
```

I'm running an in-memory cluster, so I don't know why I'm seeing this. I thought setting `"dfs.safemode.threshold.pct"` would prevent me from seeing this error based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33800253/2883245), but I was mistaken.

Why is my in-memory test cluster running in safe mode? How do I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with [`cluster.waitActive()`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/f20dc0d5770d3876954faf0a6e8dcce6539ffc23/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/MiniDFSCluster.java#L2618), which waits for the name nodes to be ready. This should have been [`cluster.waitClusterUp()`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/f20dc0d5770d3876954faf0a6e8dcce6539ffc23/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/MiniDFSCluster.java#L1379), which explicitly waits for the cluster to come out of safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to come out of safemode below running any command-

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Other commands related to safemode are

```
hadoop dfadmin -safemode get
```

to get current running status of system

Comment: I've explicitly stated that I'm running an _in-memory_ cluster -- I can't run commands on it.