# How to disable the "read only mode" in hdfs web ui?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webui

I am a beginner in Hadoop. The questions are related to the Web UI of version `Hadoop 2.8.3`.

- How to disable/change the READ ONLY MODE on the WEB UI (http://localhost:50070).

I tried getting the info from the documentation, but could not figure out the configuration to change/disable the READ ONLY MODE.

- How to implement simple authentification (user/password).

In the documentation (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/HttpAuthentication.html) there is some configuration, but I don't know how does it work.

I am not sure with the configuration. Therefore, I am looking for a simple explanation.

Comment: You mean STANDBY mode? That means your cluster isn't healthy... And Authentication requires Kerberos, which is too broad to answer on Stackoverflow

Comment: no I mean READ ONLY MODE on hdfs WEB UI.

Comment: The documentation say that we can use simply authentication with user/password : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/HttpAuthentication.html

Comment: Are you referring to `safe mode`?

Comment: *Hadoop HTTP web-consoles can be configured to **require Kerberos** authentication using HTTP SPNEGO protocol*... That other `user.name` property does not take a password, and can be literally any user

Answer (score 1):

> Safemode for the NameNode is essentially a read-only mode for the HDFS cluster

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode

You can [try to leave it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave) but without more information, your cluster is currently in a bad state, and you need to fix whatever the issue is (such as removing corrupt blocks) before it'll let you attempt to write to disk again.

> How to implement simple authentification

Without Kerberos within Hadoop or some other proxy software *in front of* the Hadoop UI that adds Basic Auth, there is no password protected setup.

Comment: Now I'am not in safe mode but when i try to create a file with hdfs WEB UI I have this message : ##Permission denied: user=dr.who, access=WRITE, inode="/":hduser:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x##

Comment: so Kerberos is the only way. thank you for your answer.

Comment: and in hdfs WEB UI can we upload file into hdfs ? or juste create a directory ?

Comment: I don't typically use NameNode UI to do much... I use Hue/Ambari or the CLI to browse HDFS

Comment: There is WebHDFS, put there are 2 requests 1) create a file 2) write contents to file. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File

Comment: hum ok I understand how to do with WebHDFS but my question is for hdfs WEB UI I would like that user don't need to go to cli for upload file but only use hdfs web UI. It is possible ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I do not often use the included Namenode UI, and as of Hadoop 2.7 that I have, I see no upload feature, or even creating a directory. Ambari might have uploading, but I know Hue has it for sure