# How to solve the following issue for Spark : org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException / What is the cause?

Tags: apache-spark

How to solve org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1669132812383_14028. Name node is in safe mode.
Resources are low on NN.

What is the cause of the issue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave

Answer (score 0):

I was able to force leaving the safe node with the following command:

```bash
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the cause of the issue was a master node nearly full (less than 500MB left).